# Ajax-ed in content not getting stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, stylesheet

[image]

I have attached an screenshot of two pages side by side. In the left side the form element in the top right is loaded as part of the full page, and is fully styled with twitter Bootstrap's styles for the grey `well`, the `form-inline`, etc.

On the right, the form is loaded via an ajax call, the code being:

```
function load(element, id){
    $.get("/lazyLoads/" + id, function(data){
        $(element).replaceWith($(data.childNodes))
    })
}
```

And you can see that the form does not get *most* of bootstrap's styles. Apart from it looking like a dog's vomit, in the Inspect Element you can clearly see that it is not matching the *most* of Bootstrap's css rules.

*most*? Yes, *most*, but not all: it seems to match Bootstrap's `form` style, but it doesn't seem to pick up the `.form-inline` or `.well` styles! The page is pretty basic and the HTML is (almost) all there for you to see. Also, i am unable to put the cursor into the text boxes to start typing on the Ajaxed page.

Apart from this CSS strangeness, the only difference is that the Ajaxed page has its `<script>` tags removed, as would be expected from a Jquery insert.

This is very mysterious to me. Tested in both Chrome and Firefox, with identical behavior. Also tested with `insertBefore`, `before`, `insertAfter`, `after`, all of which give the same behaviour. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: Still haven't managed to get a demo working (trying to get a Play 2.0 app deployed is non trivial) but here's another symptom:

If, on the right hand page (without the styles) in the Inspect Element pane I right-click on the `<form>...</form>` tag and select [Edit as HTML], don't make any changes, and leave editing mode, the styles immediately appear and the `<form>` suddenly looks like the form on the left! Clearly the HTML is fine.

Comment: Why is there a extra spaces in all class attribute?

Comment: If you're talking about plain CSS rules, then they are automatically applied to all content as soon as the objects are rendered in the page.  The only reason they wouldn't be applying would have to be something to do with a missing ID or classname somewhere that makes the CSS rules not apply.  I've seen this myself before with a period in the classname on the objects or a slight misspelling somewhere in a higher-level class.  Without the actual content for us to see, there's no much we can do.

Comment: And can you put the demo up so we can test it too?

Comment: If you notice correctly the form is applied to the second picture, so its not the problem of css. There is something else, so put up a demo.

Comment: Another guess might be that what you think are spaces between your class names are not really spaces.

Comment: Another thing to look for is invalid quoting.  Word processors will sometimes replace normal double quotes with fancy slanted double quotes which are not recognized by the HTML parser.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll post up a demo ASAP. Thanks guys!

Comment: Added another symptom. Still working on getting a demo up

Comment: Your debugger should show (somewhere) a "breadcrumb trail" when you select an element; that will tell you exactly what classes and IDs it *thinks* are applied to your element and the ones containing it. This should help narrow down the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will sometimes be NOT applied if the element has inline style definitions.
You can give your CSS definitions more priority by adding !important to your definitions.

Eg:

```
p {
   font-size: !important;
}
```

Also, in your code, I'm not sure if I misunderstood the function name "replaceWith()".

```
function load(element, id){
    $.get("/lazyLoads/" + id, function(data){
        $(element).replaceWith($(data.childNodes))
    })
}
```

Instead of that, try using the below code :

```
function load(element, id){
    $.get("/lazyLoads/" + id, function(data){
        $(element).html($(data.childNodes));
       //$(element).append($(data.childNodes));
    })
}
```